# Proving that if $x^2+y^2+xy=x+y$, then $0\le x+y\le \frac 43$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

Tags: predicate-logic

So the question I've been trying to solve is :

for $(x, y)$ in $R²$ $x^2 + y^2 + xy = x + y \Rightarrow 0 \le x + y \le \frac{4}{3}$

I've tried two things so far :

- I have put $t = (x+y)$ so the first equation becomes $t² -t -xy = 0$ this means that $1 + 4xy \ge 0$ , I've tried some things with this but nothing.
- I've tried proving that for $(x,y)$ in $R²$ $x + y > \frac{4}{3} $ OR $ x + y < 0 => x² + y² + xy$  is different that  $x + y$, since ($P=>Q$) is the same thing as (not Q $=>$ not P)

Comment: are the $x,y$ positive?

Comment: no in they're in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x+y=a,xy=b$. Then, we have
$$a^2-b=a,$$
i.e.
$$b=a^2-a.$$

By the way, since $x,y$ are the real roots of $t^2-at+b=0$, we have
$$(-a)^2-4\cdot 1\cdot b\ge 0,$$
i.e.
$$a^2-4(a^2-a)\ge 0,$$
i.e.
$$0\le a\le\frac 43.$$

Comment: can you please add more steps between the roots of  t²−at+b=0 and the next steps ?

Comment: @maetsoh: The roots are real, so the discriminant has to be non-negative.

Comment: @maetsoh: $x,y$ are the real roots of $(t-x)(t-y)=0,$ i.e. $t^2-(x+y)t+xy=0,$ i.e. $t^2-at+b=0$.

Comment: what is t ? is t = x + y ?

Comment: @maetsoh: No. I just used $t$ to express an equation which has $x,y$ as the real roots. There is another way to get $a^2-4b\ge 0$ : you can have $(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy=a^2-4b$. Since $(x-y)^2$ is non-negative, we have $a^2-4b\ge 0$.

Comment: I'll try what you suggested, because I've already tried the thing with the discriminant  for  x² + y² + xy = x + y, I've put  t = x + y the equation became  t² − t − xy = 0, and it gave me 1+4xy ≥ 0

Comment: @maetsoh: OK. Then, do you have anything unclear? Note that $t$ is not important, you can write $t^2-at+b=0$ as $p^2-ap+b=0,q^2-aq+b=0$ or $s^2-as+b=0$. In any case, the equation has $x,y$ as the real roots, so the discriminant $(-a)^2-4b$ has to be non-negative.

Comment: why do we suppose that x,y are roots of t² − at + b = 0 ?

Comment: @maetsoh: You agree that $x,y$ are the real roots of an equation $(t-x)(t-y)=0$, don't you? Then, expanding the left hand side gives $(t-x)(t-y)=t^2-ty-tx+xy=t^2-(x+y)t+xy=t^2-at+b$, right? So, $t^2-at+b=0$ has $x,y$ as the real roots.

Comment: yes I totally agree with what you've written but what's the connection between this and the equation in my question ? $x^2+y^2+xy=x+y$ .

Comment: @maetsoh: From the equation in your question, we have $b=a^2-a$, right? And since $x,y$ are the real roots of $t^2-at+b=0$, we have that the discriminant $(-a)^2-4b$ has to be non-negative, i.e. $(-a)^2-4b\ge 0$. Now since $b=a^2-a$, we have $(-a)^2-4(a^2-a)\ge 0$, now solve this.

Comment: oh I feel dumb. Thanks a lot